# Observable with Stateful Lifecycle

Tags: dart, observable, reactivex

The general design problem can be described as:

I have a websocket connection that has a strict lifecycle to respect—it wants `connect` and `disconnect` to be called appropriately, and, because it talks to the system, it uses . Within this websocket connection, we have multiple different Subscription objects, each with a strict lifecycle that it wants to be respected (`subscribe` and `unsubscribe`), and it depends on the state of its parent websocket for those operations to be successful.

Here's a timeline of the ideal behavior for three nested lifecycle observables, where C depends on B which depends on A:

```
A = someInput.switchMap((i) => LifecycleObservable())
B = A.switchMap((a) => LifecycleObservable())
C = B.switchMap((b) => LifecycleObservable())

C.listen(print);
```

```dart
// <-- listen to c
// <-- produce [someInput]
setup A
setup B
setup C
// <-- c is produced

// <-- c is unsubscribed
teardown C
teardown B
teardown A

// <-- C is re-subscribed-to
setup A
setup B
setup C

// <-- produce [someInput]
teardown C
teardown B
teardown A
setup A
setup B
setup C
// <-- c is produced
```

**First question:** Is this an anti-pattern? I haven't been able to find much about this pattern on the web, but it seems like a pretty standard sort of thing you'd run into with observables: some objects just have a lifecycle and some objects might want to depend on that.

I can get pretty close to this ideal behavior using something like this:

```dart
class LifecycleObservable {
  static Observable<T> fromObservable<T>({
    @required Observable<T> input,
    @required Future<void> Function(T) setup,
    @required Future<void> Function(T) teardown,
  }) {
    return input.asyncMap((T _input) async {
      await setup(_input);
      return _input;
    }).switchMap((T _input) {
      return Observable<T>(Observable.never()) //
          .startWith(_input)
          .doOnCancel(() async {
        await teardown(_input);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This code accepts a stream of stateful objects, running `setup` on them as they're produced and `teardown` on them as the sub-observable within the `switchMap` is cancelled.

The problem occurs when, in the original idealized timeline, the second `[someInput]` is produced: using the code above I get a callgraph like

```
// <-- listen to c
// <-- produce [someInput]
setup A
setup B
setup C
// <-- c is produced

// <-- produce [someInput]
teardown A
setup A
teardown B
setup B
teardown C
setup C
// <-- c is produced
```

the problem being that if B depends on A (like calling `unsubscribe` from a subscription that depends on an open websocket transport), this teardown order breaks the expected lifecycle of each object (the subscription tries to send `unsubscribe` over a closed websocket transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that, quite simply, **the observable pattern cannot express these semantics**. Specifically, the observable pattern is not designed for cascading dependencies—parent observables know nothing about the state of their child observables.

I solved this problem for myself with the following dart code. I'm sure it's terrible, but it seems to work for me in general™.

```dart
class WithLifecycle<T> {
  final FutureOr<void> Function() setup;
  final FutureOr<void> Function() teardown;
  final T value;
  final WithLifecycle parent;

  List<WithLifecycle> _children = [];
  bool _disposed = false;
  WithLifecycle({
    @required this.value,
    this.setup,
    this.teardown,
    this.parent,
  });

  void addDependency(WithLifecycle child) => _children.add(child);
  void removeDependency(WithLifecycle child) => _children.remove(child);
  Future<void> init() async {
    parent?.addDependency(this);
    await setup();
  }

  Future<void> dispose() async {
    if (_disposed) {
      return;
    }

    _disposed = true;
    for (var _child in _children) {
      await _child.dispose();
    }
    _children.clear();
    await teardown();
  }
}
```

which is then used to create the necessary dependency chain when using observables:

```dart
class LifecycleObservable {
  static Observable<WithLifecycle<T>> fromObservable<T>({
    @required Observable<T> value,
    WithLifecycle parent,
    @required Future<void> Function(T) setup,
    @required Future<void> Function(T) teardown,
  }) {
    return value.concatMap((T _value) {
      final withLifecycle = WithLifecycle<T>(
        value: _value,
        parent: parent,
        setup: () => setup(_value),
        teardown: () => teardown(_value),
      );
      return Observable<WithLifecycle<T>>(Observable.never())
          .startWith(withLifecycle)
          .doOnListen(() async {
        await withLifecycle.init();
      }).doOnCancel(() async {
        await withLifecycle.dispose();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

which is used like

```dart
token$ = PublishSubject();
    channel$ = token$.switchMap((token) {
      return LifecycleObservable.fromObservable<IOWebSocketChannel>(
          value: Observable.just(IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Constants.connectionString)),
          setup: (channel) async {
            print("setup A ${channel.hashCode}");
          },
          teardown: (channel) async {
            print("teardown A ${channel.hashCode}");
            await channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
          });
    });

    streams$ = channel$.switchMap((channel) {
      return LifecycleObservable.fromObservable<Stream<String>>(
        parent: channel,
        value: Observable.just(channel.value.stream.cast<String>()),
        setup: (thing) async {
          print("setup B ${thing.hashCode}");
        },
        teardown: (thing) async {
          print("teardown B ${thing.hashCode}");
        },
      );
    });

    messages = streams$.flatMap((i) => i.value).share();
```

and ends up with a call graph like the below

```
// <- push [token]
flutter: setup A 253354366
flutter: setup B 422603720
// <- push [token]
flutter: teardown B 422603720
flutter: teardown A 253354366
flutter: setup A 260164938
flutter: setup B 161253018
```